# Include a URL in a Django template tag

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building a Django blog app, since that's apparently what all the cool kids are doing.  I've built a template tag to display only the beginning of the post if it's long, and ideally to include a link to the whole post.  I started looking into escaping and IsSafe=True, but my worry is that the content itself could have HTML tags in it that could mess things up.

Here's what I have now:

```
@register.filter(name='shorten')
def shorten(content):
    #will show up to the first 500 characters of the post content
    if len(content) > 500:
        return content[:500] + '...' + <a href="/entry/{{post.id}}">(cont.)</a>
    else:
        return content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter(name='shorten')
def shorten(content, post_id):
    #will show up to the first 500 characters of the post content
    if len(content) > 500:
        output = "{0}... <a href='/entry/{1}'>(cont.)</a>".format(content[:500], post_id)
    else:
        output = "{0}".format(content)

    return mark_safe(output)
```

Comment: Hmm... clearly getting closer.  Am I correct that it should be (noting the quotes):  

`output = "{0}... <a href='/entry/{{post.id}}'>(cont.)</a>".format(content[:500])`

Comment: Without changing the quotes, I get a syntax error.  With it, it redirects to /entry/%7bpost.id%7d.

Comment: you need to pass the valid `post.id`

Comment: Ok I modified my answer so that can you understand it.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm unfamiliar with the {0} syntax; can you tell me what that's called so I can look it up and learn it?  It looks helpful.

Comment: it's Python 3+ syntax that is equivalent to `%s` in Python 2+